# Любая сущность, что проинициализирована — литерал?

Tags: информатика

Будь то объект\массив\символ\число - все имеет фиксированное значение и считается литералом?

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB_(%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)

Comment: Почему? Ну создал и инициализировал я переменную `int x = 13;`, это ведь не значит, что теперь `x` — литерал. Под литералом обычно подразумеваются: числовые константы (`13`, `0x23`, `003`, `3.1415`, `23e3`), символьные (`a`, `\0`), строковые литералы (`"hello"`) и т. д.

Comment: Литерал — это просто форма записи конкретного значения в языке программирования. В вышеупомянутом `x = 13` икс не будет литералом, потму что за иксом может прятаться какое угодно значение (можно написать `x = x + 1` и икс станет 14), а `13` это литерал, потому что где его ни напиши, значение всегда будет получаться ровно 13, а не 14, не 7 и не 451.